# How do I run an array list through the equation y = 3x + 2

Tags: python, list

I have a lab where in one part I need to use the array:

```
A = [3, 3, 20, 8, -2, 1, 3, -7, 2, 1, 3, -5, 13]
```

and I have to run all the elements of that array in this equation `Y = 3x + 2`, the `x` will be the elements of the array `A` and all the elements need to be used there, but I don't know how to make this. Also, it needs to be in a function with the name `Ecuacion, e.g.:` def Ecuacion():`

Edit: Then I need to print the elements I got from the equation.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for` loop should do the trick:

```py
for x in A:
    y = 3 * x + 2
    print(y)
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know what output I get, thank you.

edit: it did work thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
def func(A):
    B = list(map(lambda x: x * 3 + 2, A))
    return B

A = [3, 3, 20, 8, -2, 1, 3, -7, 2, 1, 3, -5, 13]
print(func(A))
```

Comment: I have tried all you guys answered and all methods worked thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

That should work

```
def ecuacion(x):
    B = []
    for i in x:
        y = 3*i + 2
        B.append(y)
    return B

A = [3, 3, 20, 8, -2, 1, 3, -7, 2, 1, 3, -5, 13]
print(ecuacion(A))
```

Output:

```
[11, 11, 62, 26, -4, 5, 11, -19, 8, 5, 11, -13, 41]
```

Comment: It did work too